# convert to lxml sax interface from default python xml.sax

Tags: python, xml, sax, lxml, wikipedia

I'm looking to speed up the parsing of a portion of Wikipedia, around 5gb. Right now im using a script that uses pythons sax interface, and lxml seems to be a straight forward solution for a speed up.

However, I'm a bit confused on by the lxml sax doc's, so any pointers/links to simple examples would be helpful. Here is the script in question that I'm looking to convert, https://gist.github.com/1739351

Comment: You could try the `etree.iterparse` functionality instead. I have a script that parses Wikipedia database dumps and extracts the articles [here](https://github.com/larsmans/wiki-dump-tools/blob/master/extractpages.py).

Comment: Always helpful to read code from others who have done it before, forked. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`lxml.sax` is NOT a plug-in replacement for `xml.sax`. It provides ADD-ON features:

```
>>> import lxml.sax
>>> help(lxml.sax)
Help on module lxml.sax in lxml:

NAME
    lxml.sax - SAX-based adapter to copy trees from/to the Python standard libra
ry.

FILE
    c:\python27\lib\site-packages\lxml\sax.py

DESCRIPTION
    Use the `ElementTreeContentHandler` class to build an ElementTree from
    SAX events.

    Use the `ElementTreeProducer` class or the `saxify()` function to fire
    the SAX events of an ElementTree against a SAX ContentHandler.
[snip]
```

You have two options:

Option 1: continue with SAX, try speeding up the code by either removing all those assertions or at least making them more efficient e.g.

```
def characters(self, content):
    # assert content is not None and len(content) > 0
    assert content
    # if len(self.stack) == 0:
    if not self.stack:
        return
    if self.stack[-1] == "title":
        self.title += content
    elif self.stack[-1] == "text":
        # assert self.title is not None
        assert self.title # This assertion is gross overkill IMHO
        self.text += content
```

Option 2: Forget SAX, use an ElementTree interface, parse using `iterparse`, and clean up the tree behind you as you go. Read [this](http://effbot.org/elementtree/iterparse.htm). You have 3 choices of ElementTree interface:

(a) `import xml.etree.ElementTree as et` ... written in Python; too slow
(b) `import xml.etree.cElementTree as et` ... written in C; much faster
(c) `import lxml.etree as et` ... can be slower than (b), but has extra features.

If you need help with option (2), search SO for "[python] iterparse", then if necessary ask a separate question (i.e. don't ask in comments on this question).

Comment: Thanks John, you clarifying that it wasn't a drop in replacement steered me back to just following along the tutorial and going with the strength of lxml, its etree api.

Comment: Except, is it my reading correct that lxml (even with iterparse) is actually not a streaming parser (i.e., it builds a tree in memory)?

Comment: @mcepl: Yes it builds a tree in memory but you can prune the tree as you go -- result: best of both worlds; beats the sox off SAX. If you want to know more, search SO for "[python] iterparse".

Answer (score 0):

maybe you could try lxml.etree, it's a pythonic way to parse XML which is efficient and concise.

Comment: Yes, I would like to use the lxml.etree methods, but I need some help with understanding the iterative or sax like events similar to what is already defined in that script.

Comment: say is really simple, it read the xml file, and each time it find an opening markup it call the function startElement(tag:String, attrs:dict) of the handler and when it find a closing markup it call the function endElement(tag:String)